# How to detect WebRTC supported video codecs on native Android

Tags: android, webrtc

We have a native Android app that uses WebRTC, and we need to find out what video codecs are supported by the host device. (VP8 is always supported but H.264 is subject to the device having a compatible chipset.)

The idea is to create an offer and get the supported video codecs from the SDP. We can do this in a web app as follows:

```
const pc = new RTCPeerConnection();

if (pc.addTransceiver) {
    pc.addTransceiver('video');
    pc.addTransceiver('audio');
}

pc.createOffer(...);
```

Is there a way to do something similar on Android? It's important that we don't need to request camera access to create the offer.

Answer (score 3):

Create a VideoEncoderFactory object and call getSupportedCodecs(). This will return a list of codecs that can be used. Be sure to create the PeerConnectionFactory first.

```
PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions initializationOptions =
            PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions.builder(this)
                    .setEnableVideoHwAcceleration(true)
                    .createInitializationOptions();
PeerConnectionFactory.initialize(initializationOptions);

VideoEncoderFactory videoEncoderFactory = 
new DefaultVideoEncoderFactory(eglBase.getEglBaseContext()
            , true, true);

for (int i = 0; i < videoEncoderFactory.getSupportedCodecs().length; i++) {
    Log.d("Codecs", "Supported codecs: " + videoEncoderFactory.getSupportedCodecs()[i].name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
private static void codecs() {
    MediaCodecInfo[] codecInfos = new MediaCodecList(MediaCodecList.ALL_CODECS).getCodecInfos();
    for(MediaCodecInfo codecInfo : codecInfos) {
        Log.i("Codec", codecInfo.getName());
        for(String supportedType : codecInfo.getSupportedTypes()){
            Log.i("Codec", supportedType);
        }
    }
}
```

You can check example on https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo.html

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, there being an H.264 codec available doesn't necessarily mean that the WebRTC engine supports it on the given device.